# Reusing the already randomly generated number in another JS file - Node.js (ESM not CJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

I need help with my project. I am creating CLI game with Node.js using ESM (not CJS).

In my `randomHealth.js` file, I have a function that generates a random number:

```js
let randomHealth = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 + 1)
}

export default randomHealth
```

In my `stats.js` file I need to import and display that number. However, I needs to be fixed there, because I need that same number in another file:

```js
import random from "./random/random.js"
import randomHealth from "./random/randomHealth.js"

let stats = () => {
  console.log("STATS")

  let playerHealth = randomHealth()
  console.log("Health - " + playerHealth)
}

export default stats
```

I stored it in a `playerHealth` variable because I need to take that one generated number.

Now, I need that variable in another file, `fight.js` to use it.
If I call `randomHealth()` it's just gonna generate a new number, and I need a number that was already generated in `stats.js` file.
How to get that number from `stats.js` to use it in `fight.js` ?

I tried exporting that variable and importing it in `fight.js`, but once I do `console.log()` it displays *undefined*. I tried many different things but none worked. It returns either *undefined*, either *NaN* either nothing. I also tried immediatelly storing it in a variable in `randomHealth.js` and then displaying it, but that didn't work either. If I do `console.log` in `randomHealth.js` then I need to do it again when I want to display it in another file and a double `console.log` displays *undefined*. And if I don't to `console.log` in `randomHealth.js` then it always regenerates a new random number and I need the number that gets displayed in `stats.js` to use in `fight.js`.

Any ideas ? This was just my idea, if there is an even better way of doing it that storing it in a varible in `stats.js` then by all means tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because in your stats you are not returning anything. You declare a variable and that's it. if you want to return the number value, you need to "return" before closure. like return playerHealth.

Comment: I tried to `return playerHealth` but when I import it in `fight.js` and try to display it, it shows _undefined_. I don't need to import the entire _stats_ over there, just that one variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that by calling ***randomHealth()*** every time, you redefine the health points. In order to patch it, I recommend that you store the values outside the function and export them.

stats.js :

```
import randomHealth from './randomHealth.js'

export var healthPlayer1 = randomHealth();
export var healthPlayer2 = randomHealth();
export var healthPlayer3 = randomHealth();

export let stats = () => {
    console.log("STATS")
    console.log("Player 1 - " + healthPlayer1)
    console.log("Player 2 - " + healthPlayer2)
    console.log("Player 3 - " + healthPlayer3)
}
```

main.js

```
import { stats } from './stats.js';

import { healthPlayer1, healthPlayer2, healthPlayer3 } from './stats.js';

stats(); 
// Player 1 - 211
// Player 2 - 98
// Player 3 - 240


console.log(healthPlayer1);// 211
console.log(healthPlayer2);// 98
console.log(healthPlayer3);// 240
```

Now you can just use the exported HP, maybe you should create functions that will modify the HP in the same script so you can centralize all related functions in the same script, making it more clean and easy to use.

Hope it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the result of the `randomHealth` function:

```
const randomHealth = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300 + 1)
}

export default randomHealth()
```